# jQuery div:contains select containing div

Tags: jquery

I have the following snippet...

```
jQuery("div:contains('myfield')").parent().find('#field_css_class').val('thisistheclass');
```

I want it to do the following...

- Search with all divs to find one that contains the word 'myfield'
- Select the containing DIV
- Search within this containing div for #css_class
- Insert the value

It sort of works, currently it changes the value for all instances of css_class, not just the one from the containing div.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the word 'myfield'"? What type of "word"? Please include some sample html so we get an idea of the structure

Comment: I have updated the question with some sample HTML jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

What you have would work (if I understand you correctly) except that the class-selector begins with a dot (`.`) instead of a hash (`#` -- which selects by id, not class-name), so try:

```
jQuery("div:contains('myfield')").parent().find('.css_class').val('thisistheclass');
```

Comment: It is actually an id and not a class, the name is just confusing!  I have updated the question with some sample HTML jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

I think Faust is right but there's a little more to your problem.

You could try something like,

```
$("div > div:contains('myfield')").find(".css_class").val('DesiredVal');
```

This will select all .css_class objects in a div in it that contains 'myfield' and is inside a div.

I should note that if whatever the object is that has css_class in it isn't some kind of input that may not do anything useful. If css_class is a div or span you might want to use this instead.

```
$("div > div:contains('myfield')").find(".css_class").html('DesiredVal');
```

Edit:
So I played with your jfiddle example and for some reason JQuery and $ aren't acting the same. So if the example you give you need to do this.

```
$("li div div:contains('myfield')").parent().parent().find("#field_css_class").val('thisistheclass');
```

this finds the div containing myfield then goes up 2 objects and then looks for the misleadingly named ID.

My confussion is why you don't add a unique identifer to the input like a `class='HandleThatOnlyJQueryLooksAtAndNotActuallyAClass'`

Then you could just write

```
$('.HandleThatOnlyJQueryLooksAtAndNotActuallyAClass').val('Stuff');
```

admittedly that's a ridiculous name but it wont accidentally style anything.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  Instead of changing just the .css_class in the div that contains 'myfield' it changes all of them